# Comparing hash value of password in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, hash, password-encryption

As part of learning php, I wanted to try a register and login page, however, the [site](http://alias.io/2010/01/store-passwords-safely-with-php-and-mysql/) I'm following for how to store a password uses MySQLI and I'm not using that:

**Hashing the password**

```
$password1 = 'hello123';
// A higher "cost" is more secure but consumes more processing power
$cost = 10;

// Create a random salt
$salt = strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), '+', '.');

// Prefix information about the hash so PHP knows how to verify it later.
// "$2a$" Means we're using the Blowfish algorithm. The following two digits are the cost parameter.
$salt = sprintf("$2a$%02d$", $cost) . $salt;

// Value:
// $2a$10$eImiTXuWVxfM37uY4JANjQ==

// Hash the password with the salt
$hash = crypt($password1, $salt);
```

I'm stuck on retrieving the password however, here's the site's code for it:

```
$username = 'Admin';
$password = 'gf45_gdf#4hg';

$sth = $dbh->prepare('
  SELECT
    hash
  FROM users
  WHERE
    username = :username
  LIMIT 1
  ');

$sth->bindParam(':username', $username);

$sth->execute();

$user = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

// Hashing the password with its hash as the salt returns the same hash
if ( crypt($password, $user->hash) === $user->hash ) {
  // Ok!
}
```

From what I can see, he grabs the hash value of the password for the user in the DB and compares the password that was passed using the hash and check with the one in the DB.

I've been trying this but the result hash is never the same as the original one:

```
$pwdtocheck = 'hello123';

// no call do DB yet, doing this on the same page after hashing, the $hash is the same as above
$pwdhash = crypt($pwdtocheck, $hash);

// if I echo $pwdhash it's never exactly the same as the $hash.
if ( $pwdhash === $hash) {
  echo "same pwd";
}
```

Comment: That [site's](http://alias.io/2010/01/store-passwords-safely-with-php-and-mysql/) not loading, so I can't see what the content is to compare with.

Comment: Since PHP 5.5 you can use [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/password_hash).

Comment: Also see Openwall's [PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) (PHPass). Its portable and hardened against a number of common attacks on user passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I see now that you *are* using a salt when you compare the passwords. In your line:

```
$pwdhash = crypt($pwdtocheck, $hash);
```

the `$hash` variable has the salt prepended to it because `crypt()` will automatically do that for you. `crypt()` will extract the salt from the `$hash` because it knows the expected length of the salt based on the algorithm used. [See the documentation](https://www.php.net/crypt).

I'll keep my original answer below for context and for those looking for a similar answer.

**END EDIT**

The password is not the same for you because you are using a `salt` when you originally hash the password to put in your database, but you are not salting the password later when you check against the database.

You should use the same salt string when you save the password as when you check the user's password on login. Usually, you will randomly generate the salt string for each password (as you are doing) and then save the salt string to the database along with the hashed password (either in the same column or its own column) so that you can use the same salt to check the user's password on login.

See https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#salt for reference.

Comment: That's where I was getting confused regarding the salt yeah! I thought about storing it too, but I wasn't sure I was supposed to ^^ Thank you!

Comment: This can not be the problem, because the `crypt()` function includes the salt in the resulting hash-value, and for verification it extracts the salt automatically from the stored hash-value.

Comment: I'll have a look again, but I read in several places that you have to store the salt as well when you want to compare the passwords later on.

Comment: @LanFeusT, as @martinstoeckli was saying, the PHP `crypt()` function saves the salt to the beginning of the hashed value. You can then extract it from the hash when you are comparing later on - so you don't need to store the salt separately.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see the actual problem in your code, maybe your database field is smaller than 60 characters, or you are comparing different passwords. In every case there is an easier and safer way to hash passwords, just use the new functions [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). There exists also a [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php) for earlier PHP versions.

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that tonight!

Answer (score 0):

I can't access the article you're referencing but I imagine:

You need to check using the salt as the salt and not the hash.

`crypt($pwdtocheck, $user->salt) == $user->hash`

should work